Do only 0.3% of U.S. air force applicants become fighter pilots?
Here, it says only 3 out of 1000 that apply become fighter pilots. Is this statistic true? (It seems like a very low percentage)
If so what is the main difference between the 3 compared to the remaining 997? What did the 3 do differently than the 997?
(I know that the answer probably is it depends, but what are they looking for when selecting pilots?)

Out of 1,000 what?  A thousand people who looked up at an airshow and thought "wow, cool!" -- maybe so.  Per thousand 2Lt's who start pilot training? Not even remotely.  That article isn't quite garbage, but it's pretty close. I certainly wouldn't take their statistics as gospel.  After all, 87.23% of all stats are made up on the spot!

Also highly relevant, given a quick look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_active_United_States_Air_Force_aircraft suggests that an USAF is between 10 and 25% fighter aircraft depending how you count them, and not all pilots are in flying positions. So at even given time 'fighter pilot' will be only a subset of current USAF pilots, but a larger % will be qualified to fly them.

Some older numbers for a different airforce here are probably still relevant in talking through the odds.
An airforce has fairly fixed need for number of active pilots, driven by the number of airframes. Many of those airframes are not in fact fighters, so many serving pilots are not fighter pilots.
The profession 'pilot' is one that many people think they understand, and can see themselves doing so more people will walk into a recruiting office with idea of being a pilot than say 'network technician' or 'Airborne Electronics Analyst'*.
Fighter pilot is a specifically demanding profession that requires a high degree of physical fitness, aviation, technical and tactical knowledge and ability to apply all of those under pressure where consequences of being wrong can be highly lethal.
These factors combine to mean that a military will happily let large numbers of applicants put 'pilot' at the top of their preferences form and then based on skills or lack thereof found during testing and assessment filter them into ground support, flying non pilot , pilot of non fighter aircraft and hopefully get enough actually qualified fighter pilots left over.
So a high percentage of people who show up at the recruiting tent and taking the 'how to become a fighter pilot' brochure NOT becoming fighter pilots is the system largely working efficiently from the military perspective (would be better if people showed up WANTING to become more obscure professions of course).
If you are in the position where this number matters directly to your career goals, what matters far more is the % of actually fully qualified candidates not making the cut for the current cycle, rather than % of people who the system will route into other professions.
*at time of writing listed as a priority recruiting position (faster processing and less competition) and at a higher starting salary than pilot.

Somewhere I read an article about a European country-- Sweden maybe? -- where they do things differently and the percentage of candidates entering the flight training program who get "washed out" is dramatically lower than elsewhere.  (Don't recall exactly what the article said about the fighter pilot track though-- that may be highly selective, with those not qualifying being diverted to transports etc?)

@quietflyer, certainly it is mildly deceptive to sign people up up for the pilot dream and then switch them into another profession once committed so a fairer process is certainly possible. Equally if older figher pilots define the process they may like a high washout rate because the survivors can feel 'elite', while a process setup in more civilian lines will try to only spend time on valid candidates and having spent that time be less prone to 'one mistake and out' testing.

Partial "answer" here, based purely on anecdotal experience.
This answer addresses the OP's question "If so what is the main difference between the 3 compared to the remaining 997? What did the 3 do differently than the 997?" It is based on personal observations and opinion more than anything else.
Back in the day (1982), I attended United States Air Force Undergraduate Pilot Training (UPT). On day one, there were 50 highly qualified candidates. The washout rate over the year-long course was such that only 25 of us were ultimately awarded pilot wings. IIRC, about 12 of us were deemed qualified for fighter assignments.
Over the years, I've come to conclude that the primary trait separating the graduating 25 from the washed-out 25 was the ability to learn new things quickly. I have always believed that, given enough time, our flight instructors could have made Air Force pilots of almost all of the washouts, if given enough time. However, the Air Force allowed only one year. In their defense, they could afford to be picky, since the supply of "wannabees" seemed endless at the time...
